# OpenAI API Key Works This Way, But Not That Way? Very Confused?

Tags: python, api, openai-api

I'm trying to use the OpenAI API. But my API key is valid in some code, but invalid in other code. I cannot understand why.

When I use it like this, it works:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = 'KEY'

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "What is the circumference in km of the planet Earth?"}]
)

reply_content = completion.choices[0].message.content
print(reply_content)
```

But when I use it like this, it doesn't work. I get an error stating that my API Key is invalid:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = 'KEY'

completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", messages=[{"role": "user", "content": "Give me 3 ideas for apps I could build with openai apis "}])
print(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

Why would the same key work for the above, but not for the below? Am I missing something? I'm very new to coding.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: It's in python.

Comment: OK, I've added that into the questions tags for you. It's a good idea to always include that, because the people who are most likely able to help will probably be people watching that tag. As a bonus, it automatically turns on syntax highlighting for the selected language.

Comment: Can you give us the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything wrong. Both the codes you provided are the exact same, and the only reason you would get the error you described, is if you didn't enter the same API key.

It could also be that your API somehow changed after testing the first method, try making sure that your API key is one you were actually given.